# (Flutter/Dart) How to ignore popups in didPopNext?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-routes

didPopNext understands that popup is a screen when it was popped, but i don't want to call my checkInterstitial method in this case.

what should I do to solve this?

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with RouteAware, WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final controller = Get.find<HomeUiStore>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    appRouteObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context) as PageRoute);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    appRouteObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    AdMobUtil.dispose();
    FirebaseMessagingStore.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didPushNext() {
    controller.onboardingKey.currentState?.hide();
    SnackBarUtil.instance.closeCurrentSnackbar();
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    controller.checkInterstitial();
    controller.checkShowOnboarding();
    controller.checkShowAlertSnackbar();
  }
```

I used Get.previousRoute and Get.currentRoute to find routes and ignore when previous and current are the same, because I thinked it's happened when popup is popped, but not worked

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict your [RouteObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html) to seeing only non-popup route by declaring it as `RouteObserver<PageRoute>()`.

And you can have multiple active observers at the same time.